# Append integer number to integer array in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to add a new integer value to my existing integer array in postgres table. I am using array_append method here but getting "Cannot cast type jsonb to integer[]" error. My update query is as follows.

Note- I am just using it for learning purpose so I am intentionally saving phonenumber as integer.

[image: Click here for table structure and error screenshot]

`update querytesting set jsondoc=jsondoc||jsonb_build_object(jsondoc->'PhoneNumber',array_append(((jsondoc->'PhoneNumber')::int[]),'6789')) where id=1;`

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract the array, append the new number, create a new JSON with the new array and store that.  A tedious and inefficient procedure that would be unnecessary if you had stored your data in a normalized data model instead of a JSON.

```
UPDATE querytesting
SET jsondoc = jsonb_set(
                 jsondoc,
                 '{PhoneNumber}',
                 jsondoc -> 'PhoneNumber' || JSONB '[6789]'
              );
WHERE id=1;
```